# Using a "filter" method as a regular helper method

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a method in the parent class of a controller.  It's used as a before_filter (require_user) on most methods, but I need to call it like a helper_method.  When I do so, the method doesn't get called immediately, it is called asynchronously.

I don't understand why this is happening.

Example code for the controllers and the error messages from the actual session are here https://gist.github.com/3187671

Any help is appreciated.  Thanks!

Edit:  I just found this post, which explains that it shouldn't work; but doesn't explain why it would call the helper asynchronously http://www.markhneedham.com/blog/2011/01/11/rails-using-helpers-inside-a-controller/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `redirect_to` or `render` methods do not halt the execution of the method. If you have to be sure that only one of them is called (otherwise Rails throws the DoubleRenderError, see [guide 2.2.13](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html)). That's the problem in your code `redirect_to` is called by `require_user`, and `render` is called next.

Comment: Thanks @Baldrick I still don't understand why the log messages aren't output in serial.  I would think that I would get the messages from within the require_user method before it returns to the show method of the controller.  

It doesn't appear to matter what I do in require_user because it isn't executed when I expect it to be.

Comment: Nevermind.. the synchronous stuff was just me having wonky logs.  I need to figure out how to halt the execution; I expected render and return would work.. but it seems to just return to the calling method, which is exactly what I don't want to happen.

Comment: @Greg It may be only the way that Rails print the log messages. Try to use a timestamp or an incremented global variable to be sure of the execution flow...

Comment: @Greg the `redirected_to` halt the request when called from the `before_filer`, but not when called from inside `show`. Add a return value in `require_user` and use it in `show` to halt the method.